# Convert to all upper case letter bug in C

Tags: c, debugging, toupper

I'm a noob so please explain why the following code isn't working?
It prints an unnecessary `Case 1:.` I assume it's not scanning using `fgets` the first time in the Test Case loop.

Please someone tell me why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, T;
    scanf("%d", &T); //test cases
    char character[100];
    for (j = 1; j <= T; j++) {
        fgets(character, 100, stdin); //input
        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(character); i++) { //function
            if (character[i] >= 91) {
                character[i] = character[i] - 32;
            };
        }
        printf("Case %d: %s", j, character); //result
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf` reads a number *and nothing more*. `fgets` reads up to and including the next newline character. So what does your first call to `fgets` read?

Comment: I've corrected indentation (waiting for edit approval), and it should be clear  why *Case 1* log is printed. Your logically seems mostly correct, except *toupper* part.

Comment: By the way: `character` is a really bad name for an array, which is certainly not a single character. (Anyway, names should in some way describe what the variable represents; the datatype is not usually very helpful.) And you need to get into the habit of checking return codes from all library functions, in case the function reports failure.

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Code `'Z'` not `90` at least for readability

Comment: @highAsAKite: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you should read the pending newline after getting the number with `scanf()`.
- you do not check for end of file
- you include the null terminator in the loop, a simpler test is this:

  ```
    for (i = 0; character[i] != '\0'; i++)
  ```
- you should use `<ctype.h>` to convert lower case to upper case or at least use character constants instead of hardcoded ASCII values. The current code would also convert such characters as `{`, `|`, `}`... because they happen to be >= 91.
- `91` is incorrect anyway. `'a'` has value `97` in ASCII.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, T;

    if (scanf("%d", &T)) != 1) //test cases
        return 1;
    getchar();  // read pending newline
    char character[100];
    for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
        if (!fgets(character, sizeof character, stdin)) //input
            break;
        for (i = 0; character[i] != '\0'; i++) { //function
            character[i] = toupper((unsigned char)character[i]);
        }
        printf("Case %d: %s", j + 1, character); //result
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ASCII specific version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, T;

    if (scanf("%d", &T)) != 1) //test cases
        return 1;
    getchar();  // read pending newline
    char character[100];
    for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
        if (!fgets(character, sizeof character, stdin)) //input
            break;
        for (i = 0; character[i] != '\0'; i++) { //function
            if (character[i] >= 'a' && character[i] <= 'z') {
                character[i] -= 'a' - 'A';
            }
        }
        printf("Case %d: %s", j + 1, character); //result
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my man both of your codes prints the same thing as mine... it needs to print an output with case 1: . but case 1 remians blank

Comment: Please check :
https://algo.codemarshal.org/problems/556a0cb1a843fc851d47b4cd

Comment: @highAsAKite, this is the best solution for the problem you presented. As far as we may know, the first line in your test set could actually be blank!

Comment: @highAsAKite: the issue is the counter-intuitive behavior of `scanf()` that leaves the trailing newline after the initial number pending in `stdin`. Add the `getchar()` to solve this issue.

Comment: sorry im a huge noobie..where do i use the getchar?

Comment: The memory constraint in the problem specification is ludicrous: *1024MB* :)

Comment: @chqrlie I copy pasted your code and I still get a 45/100 ... Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This code will do want you want to do.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,T;
scanf("%d\n",&T); //test cases
char character[100];
for(j=1;j<=T;j++){
fgets(character,100,stdin); //input
for(i=0;i<strlen(character);i++){ //function
        if(character[i]>=91){
            character[i]= character[i]-32;
        }
}
printf("Case %d: %s \n",j,character); //result
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seem to have solved the problem but I think it is printing 2 extra spaces and a new line... that's why it is not being accepted...
please check the problem [Problem](https://algo.codemarshal.org/problems/556a0cb1a843fc851d47b4cd)

Comment: just remove the space and \n in the printf

Comment: Alright removed the spaces and now it's showing that I got a 45/100 ...why not a 100/100? can someone take a look at the problem? https://algo.codemarshal.org/problems/556a0cb1a843fc851d47b4cd

Comment: @highAsAKite: you get a low score because you convert characters that are not lowercase letters.

Comment: use the upper and lower limits for A-Z  (91 to 122) in the if condition.

Comment: @KaranMatalia You are wrong, as I wrote in the previous comment. ASCII value for 'a' is 97 (0x61), not 91. And you don't check for upper limit. so why don't you simply check for `c>='a' && c<='z'`?

Comment: @Cubo78 yes my bad. That is also one approach, whichever the person wants to do.

Comment: @KaranMatalia: I'm afraid it is not just *also one approach* but a **much more reasonable approach**

Comment: @chqrlie why is it a **much more reasonable approach**?

Comment: Because hard-code values such as `91` are much less readable than character constants such as `'a'`, that the compiler will turn to constant values at compile time. Not only are such values non portable to non-ASCII architectures, they are so impenetrable that it took many a sharp eye to detect the error: `91` instead of `97`. One should always prefer obvious values such as `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

`for (i = 0; i <= strlen(character); i++)`

should be modified to

`for (i = 0; i < strlen(character); i++)`

Comment: This is a shortcoming, but has no consequences.

Comment: don't think that's the issue